# During Import through phpspreadsheet, getting 'undefined index $' error

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.3, phpspreadsheet

Integrated phpspreadsheet with laravel-5.3, while importing some excel files (.xlsx) getting undefined index $ error

Same error also exists when  importing through Phpexcel library

> 2018-09-26 07:05:22 : #0 /var/www/html/project/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php(291): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/html/s...', 291, Array) #1 /var/www/html/project/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php(207): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString('$A') #2 /var/www/html/project/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/AutoFilter.php(111): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::rangeBoundaries('$A$1:$K$1') #3 /var/www/html/project/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php(1076): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\AutoFilter->setRange('$A$1:$K$1') #4 /var/www/html/project/app/Excel/FileLoader.php(286): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx->load('/var/www/html/s...') #5

with in Coordinate.php (291) autoFilter are applied like this $A$1:$K$1 (or may be because of formula) so this $ sign is  creating problem both for phpspreadsheet and phpexcel.

is there any way to  disable auto filtering in phpspreadsheet? or any  other way to fix this problem. I dont want to modify library files.

> Error is thrown an soon as file is loaded through IOFactory::load method